# Debian HC4 NAS can't resolve any host

Tags: debian, networking, command-line

new to stackoverflow and linux usage, have a NAS setup on HC4 currently trying to set up a steam cache, after installing docker I was trying to install network-manager which lead me down a rabbit hole because it returned errors such as :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not resolve 'download.docker.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/dists/erasmus/InRelease  Could not resolve 'packages.openmediavault.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io/packages/debian/dists/usul/InRelease  Could not resolve 'openmediavault-plugin-developers.github.io'
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/dists/usul/InRelease  Could not resolve 'packages.openmediavault.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.linuxfactory.or.kr/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.linuxfactory.or.kr'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/omvextras.list:2
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/omvextras.list:2
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/omvextras.list:2
```

now I get those errors with apt-get update, and apt-get install network-manager returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package network-manager is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'network-manager' has no installation candidate
```

and because I messed with this a lot, here is my sources.list:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                   OFFICIAL DEBIAN REPOS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                      UNOFFICIAL  REPOS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

###### 3rd Party Binary Repos
###Docker CE
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable

###openmediavault
deb http://packages.openmediavault.org/public erasmus main
deb-src http://packages.openmediavault.org/public erasmus main
```

any help or a direction to point me in would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First off, I strongly recommend you change `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main` (and it's related deb-src line) to explicitly  point to buster: `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main` . Buster is nearing the point that they will move Buster to 'oldstable', move Sid to 'stable', and so on, which will break your system unless you fully upgrade your disttro to Sid.

Comment: Second, have you tried the conrib (and non-free) repos? That is, on each line that ends with `main`, change it to `main contrib non-free` . Then `apt-get update` then try to install "network-manager"? It's possible that one of the dependencies (or drivers our system needs) is not available from 'main'.

Comment: Third, I will go ahead and get the IP addresses for each of the repository hosts, and post them (or a link to them) so you can include them in `/ec/hosts` to help ensure they resolve so you _**can**_ `apt-get update` successfully. (I realize you solved your problem, but I will still post here for the benefit of others who may have similar issues and seek a solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright been messing around with it and the issue seems to have been that the OMV config for eth0 and the network manager config were set differently, so after manually setting both to the same settings it was able to resolve hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the office debian repositories for debian buster:

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free\